# How to set up logging in splat ReactiveUI?

Tags: c#, .net-core, reactiveui, splat

I need to enable logging in reactiveui. I implemented the `ILogger` interface:

```cs
public class Logger : Splat.ILogger
{
    public LogLevel Level { get; private set; }

    public Logger(LogLevel level)
    {
        Level = level;
    }

    public void Write([Localizable(false)] string message, LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        if (logLevel >= Level)
        Serilog.Log.Error(message);
    }

    public void Write(Exception exception, [Localizable(false)] string message, LogLevel logLevel)
    {
    if (logLevel >= Level)
        Serilog.Log.Error(exception, message);
    }

    public void Write([Localizable(false)] string message, [Localizable(false)] Type type, LogLevel logLevel)
    {
    if (logLevel >= Level)
        Serilog.Log.Error(message);
    }

    public void Write(Exception exception, [Localizable(false)] string message, [Localizable(false)] Type type, LogLevel logLevel)
    {
    if (logLevel >= Level)
        Serilog.Log.Error(exception, message);
    }
}
```

and register it:

```cs
var logger = new Logging.Logger(LogLevel.Info) { };
Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant(logger, typeof(ILogger));
```

And trying to use it like this:

```cs
LogHost.Default.Error("TestTestTest");

this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.IsHierarchical).Log(this, "ClusterableDictionaryValueSelector IsHierarchical exception")
.BindTo(this, x => x.ViewModel.IsHierarchical).DisposeWith(disposables);
```

But I can't found the log file. And when I call `LogHost.Default` no method is called. What's wrong?

Comment: Why not use the pre-made Serilog logger we made for ReactiveUI? https://github.com/reactiveui/splat#serilog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a premade Serilog logger that is made for Splat.

You should be able to register it using

```cs
using Splat.Serilog;

// Then in your service locator initialisation
locator.CurrentMutable.UseSerilogWithWrappingFullLogger();
```

See https://github.com/reactiveui/splat#serilog for further details.

Then you would just register the logger as per normal.

The Splat Serilog also supports semantic logging out of the box, while the `ILogger` would strip that information.

Comment: It's working, but how to enable this:
```csharp
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.IsHierarchical).Log(this, "ClusterableDictionaryValueSelector IsHierarchical exception")
.BindTo(this, x => x.ViewModel.IsHierarchical).DisposeWith(disposables);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. LoggedCatch will call if there is an error in the ReactiveUI, right?

Comment: Will capture any exceptions passed into your observable stream, log them, and also allow you to pass it on in a new stream.